# Query string PHP

Tags: php

I have url xyz.com/s2d3f4 which redirects to xyz.com/index.php.I want to capture s2d3f4.i have tried query string and it does not work .Any suggestions on how to get that value?I am using http redirect.

Comment: How is your redirect relized?

Comment: Could you possibly rephrase this as an understandable question? I'd suggest reading [Jon Skeet's 'Writing the Perfect Question' blog entry](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Comment: How are you redirecting?  Is it a simple `header("Location: index.php");` or are you using some sort of mod_rewrite (or some other option)?

Comment: Redirect happens with mod_rewrite? If so, take a look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. It may as well help to check `print_r($_SERVER)`.

Comment: How does the redirect work? Is it a mod_rewrite, or a HTTP redirect (i.e. performed by the client), if the latter, you won't be able to get the previous URL (exception might be the referrer, but a client can disable that..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every HTTP request is independent by design, so if you do a HTTP redirect (with `header("Location: http://xyz.com/index.php")` in PHP or `RewriteRule ^ /index.php [R]` in `.htaccess`) and the user sees `http://xyz.com/index.php` in the browser, then the original URL information is lost.

You can manually save it by

- adding it to the query string: `http://xyz.com/index.php?s=s2d3f4`;
- saving it in a session cookie ([`session_start`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) etc.).

On the other hand, if you are actually doing an internal redirect, so the user still sees `http://xyz.com/s2d3f4` in the browser but it's handled by `index.php`, then

- `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will hold the original URL (`/s2d3f4`);
- you can also redirect with a query string (e.g., `RewriteRule .* index.php?s=$0`) and then that information will be available in `$_REQUEST['s']`.

Answer (score 0):

> Did you try **PATH_INFO**  or
>   'ORIG_PATH_INFO

$HTTP_SERVER_VARS [deprecated]
$_SERVER -- $HTTP_SERVER_VARS [deprecated] — Server and execution environment information

Anyway Try it

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php