# Wrong url redirects to index page

Tags: php

I type xyz.com/1234(1234 is jargon) it takes me to xyz.com/index.php. I am using apache and mod_rewrite does not have any rule for this .Index page is not even the default page setup by the DirectoryIndex.I am puzzled why it takesto the index page.

Comment: are you using some framework/CMS? Can you post your htaccess?  You haven't really give us enough information.

Comment: no not using a framework or cms.

Comment: Jargon, n. [slang]: a characteristic language of a particular group.

Comment: Duplicate much? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081902/query-string-php

Comment: Is it possible that there is a custom 404 page with just a redirect to http://www.xyz.com/index.php on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try whether it gets better with

```
Options -Multiviews
```

in the .htaccess file. If it doesn't, there must be a rewrite rule somewhere, or maybe an ErrorDocument directive (although that shouldn't redirect).

Answer (score 0):

You can see if it's mod_rewrite doing it to you easily by cranking up rewrite logging to insane levels:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLogLevel 10
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
```

Post your apache config and the relevant .htaccess file and we might be able to be more help.